# My Android project Build Failed and never execute the project?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-studio, android-studio-import

My question is, I was try to change the package name of my android project, when I build my project it's give me error, And then I pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> button to rewrite my package name before and try to built it again it's not build my project.
my error is 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

First you see the screen shot
[image: Screen shot of Android manifest file]

now you see my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.tabsample"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
}
```

I have a latest build version

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

and also I tried to clean and rebuild the project and also I tried to restart the Android studio but the error not goes. It's my complete whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the first error, you have a space which is an invalid character in the category tag it should be `<category android:name=android.intent.category.default/>`.

Comment: Thanks man for you're answered. I found this error and also resolved it in same day as I was posted this question.You're answered totally correct.